# What are the supported ICP roles configuration for a node?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

Is it possible to assign multiples roles to one node in an IBM Cloud Private (ICP) cluster?

For example: if I have 5 physical servers and I want to implement an HA cluster - can I deploy the following architecture?

> **server 1**: master + boot + worker
>
> **server 2**: master + proxy + worker
>
> **server 3**: master + worker
>
> **server 4**: worker
>
> **server 5**: worker

Will it be a supported architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is supported by ICP. You can assign multiple roles for each node, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your planned HA architecture is supported by ICP. However, it would be recommended to have a only a node for only master + boot and a dedicated proxy node. Such as the following architecture:

```
server 1: master + boot

server 2: master + worker

server 3: master + worker

server 4: worker

server 5: proxy
```

You can find more information here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.2.0/getting_started/architecture.html

Note: If you assign multiple roles to one node, you have to increase the hardware resources of that node to meet the minimum requirements of multiple roles

"If you do not use a management node in your multi-node cluster, ensure that the master node meets the requirements of the management node plus the master node."

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.2.0/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html#multi

"If multiple cluster roles are installed on one node, the disk requirement is the sum of the disk requirement for each role. In the production environment, it is not recommended to install multiple cluster roles on one node."

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_3.2.0/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html#multi

ICP Support Portal: http://ibm.biz/icpsupport
ICP Public Slack Channel: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W1559b1be149d_43b0_881e_9783f38faaff/page/Connect